# Remove double quotes from Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json object.when i do JSON.stringify it looks like below

```
{
    "bindto": {},
    "data": {
        "type": "line",
        "columns": "[['SO_Lat',1361.213042,7494.897354000001],['SO_Long',1361.213042,7494.897354000001]]",
        }
}
```

I want to convert column field without double quotes and send it back to server my final output will be like this

```
{
        "bindto": {},
        "data": {
            "type": "line",
            "columns": [['SO_Lat',1361.213042,7494.897354000001],['SO_Long',1361.213042,7494.897354000001]],
            }
    }
```

Please help

Comment: Where are you getting this from? (side-note, there is *no such thing* as a "JSON object")

Comment: Why? That would be invalid JSON. Actually turns out that your first example doesn't validate either.

Comment: i am creating it maually

Comment: Don't do that. Use a json encoder/decoder. Show us what you start with - prior to stringify.

Comment: @jay it wont see here http://c3js.org/samples/axes_label_position.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh boy this is hacky.

```
obj.data.columns = JSON.parse('{"x":' + obj.data.columns.replace(/'/g, '"') + '}').x
```

That string isn't JSON, so this basically forces it to be JSON and parses it. Barely better than an eval.

Comment: @Max that's pretty cool! Also that last comma in "data" should be removed

Comment: @user3106347 Max creates a new object called "x" and sets its value to be equal to whatever is inside of obj.data.columns (but with `'` replaced with `"`). That parses as a valid JSON and returns object containing `x` property. `JSON.parse(...).x` reads that `x` property replaces `obj.data.columns` with it.

Comment: Hi, my object is like this `{year: "2019", month: "02", day: "16"}` and I want to convert it as `{year: 2019, month: 02, day: 16}. Any ideas please ?